# Delay bind click execution

Tags: jquery, bind, delay

I am running this into a document ready but i guess i am not doing it right :)

```
$('.wall-action-item ').bind('click', function() {
  $('#activity-feed').waterfall('reLayout', $('#activity-feed'), function() {});
}).delay( 1500 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```

Its a function to refresh waterfall content. i have some ajax content generated when i click on comments for example. its working only if i click .wall-action-item two times so i guess i need to set some delay or duplicate it. i am lost...

Comment: that doesn't make sense... If you wait 10 seconds and then click it, does it also take 2 clicks? how long are you waiting between clicks?

Comment: all i can asume is the first click is not working and the second does..

Comment: That doesn't make sense though. If the 2nd click works, that means the first click works too. It's more likely that said plugin isn't working instead, that or the first click isn't actually happening (meaning you're clicking something else entirely)

Comment: You are right. i am such an idiot. first time i was clicking the comments link which is sliding down a comment textarea. i changed the click selector into comment-action but still no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing your second parameter. It should be like this:

```
$('.wall-action-item ').bind('click', function() {
    $('#activity-feed').waterfall('reLayout', function() {
         alert('relayout done!');
    });
}).delay( 1500 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```